# Stripe.net Checkout Success Insecure

Tags: c#, blazor, stripe-payments

I am working on completing my checkout process for my Blazor WASM application. When I get a successful checkout and Stripe redirects to my site I find that the success page is no longer secure.

User Flow:

- User loads Site (Blazor WASM)
- User logs in (OAuth provider, the redirect from the oauth service is secure)
- User checks out via stripe
- Success redirect from stripe is not secure

```
[HttpPost]
[Route(nameof(CreateStripCheckoutSession))]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateStripCheckoutSession([FromForm] string subType)
{
    string domain = "https://www.localhost:{port}/";

    string priceId = await GetPriceId(subType.ToLower());


    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
        {
          new SessionLineItemOptions
          {
            Price = priceId,
            Quantity = 1,
          },
        },
        Mode = "subscription",
        SuccessUrl = domain + "CheckoutSuccess",
        CancelUrl = domain + "CheckoutCancel",
        AutomaticTax = new SessionAutomaticTaxOptions { Enabled = true },
        ClientReferenceId = "test client",
        Customer = GetOrCreateCustomer().Id,
        CustomerUpdate = new SessionCustomerUpdateOptions
        {
            Address = "auto"
        },
        SubscriptionData = new SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
        {
            TrialPeriodDays = 30,
        },
    };
    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = service.Create(options);

    Response.Headers.Add("Location", session.Url);
    return new StatusCodeResult(303);
}
```

When the site loads there is all requests are successful and show that they were completed using HTTPS. However, the page puts a strike through the https in the URL bar and states that the page is not secure. The browser says the error is `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

I have moved all local host ssl certs to the trusted root folder; I have have trusted the dev certificates.

If I navigate to the success page manually the page loads securely. It only ever loads insecurely when it is redirected from Stripe.

Also, I am using the latest version of Visual Studio Preview (17.7.0 Preview 2.0)

Comment: Are you posting back to a public domain name? Is that host name listed as a `subjectAlternativeName` on the certificate? Are you using the external IP address to call back to your server. The Stripe checkout process is tried and true, so this is very specific to your implementation. Check that the host URL in the browser in the redirect back is the _same_ as the host before your redirected to stripe. ( I use Stripe in Blazor, absolutely love it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove the www. in the domain.

```
string domain = "https://localhost:{port}/";
```